# xslt for adding prefixes to my property names in the xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document in this format.

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
<Header>
<Id>123</Id>
</header>
<Properties>
<property name= "type" value = "a1">
<property name="prop1" value="val1"/>
<property name="prop2" value="val2"/>
</Properties>
<Properties>
<property name= "type" value = "a2">
<property name="prop1" value="val1"/>
<property name="prop2" value="val2"/>
</Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

I am unable to write an xslt transformation that transforms my xml document into something like

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
<Header>
<Id>123</Id>
</Header>
<Properties>
<property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
<property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
<property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
<property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
</Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

Can I, please, get some help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <SampleXMLFormat>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
    <Properties>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Properties>
  </SampleXMLFormat>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property[not(@name='type')]">
  <property name="{../property[@name='type']/@value}_{@name}" value="{@value}"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name= "type" value = "a1"/>
    <property name="prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="prop2" value="val2"/>
  </Properties>
  <Properties>
    <property name= "type" value = "a2"/>
    <property name="prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="prop2" value="val2"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
   <Header>
      <Id>123</Id>
   </Header>
   <Properties>
      <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
      <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
      <property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
      <property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
   </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of:

1. **[Template match patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns)**.
2. **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** s (Attribute Value Templates).

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri, I edited this answer to implement the newly-formulated requirement. Please, if you still have other variations, consider asking a new question. This question has been fully answered -- twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But i just removed my edits considering i figured it out myself..I cant thank you more..It is your answer that helped me figure it out..Do you want me to edit your answer instead..or edit back my question again.

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri, You are welcome. If you edit your question, just let me know, and I will synchronize the answer.

Comment: I didnt notice this but why am i now seeing an extra 123 under properties.The xslt transformation could be wrong. Even your output gives that

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri, Copy/paste error -- will correct in a moment.

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output It gets validated here. But throws this error/The XSL Transformer fully supports XML namespaces, but the declarations MUST be explicit and MUST be on the root XML element of both your XML file and your XSL file. See the XSLT Examples section for details.I am using an internal declarative language at my company and even it fails this transformation.Do u think there is something wrong with the way we added our header tags in xslt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28858/discussion-between-anusha-pachunuri-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri, If you are using incompliant/buggy XSLT processor, I can't help you with this. I have 11 different XSLT processors on my PC and all they produce the above result.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not well-formed, but assuming that this is what you meant it to be (note the terminated "type" properties):

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Properties>
    <property name= "type" value = "a1"/>
    <property name="prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="prop2" value="val2"/>
  </Properties>
  <Properties>
    <property name= "type" value = "a2"/>
    <property name="prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="prop2" value="val2"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

Then this XSLT should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Properties>
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="Properties/*[not(self::property and 
                                   @name = 'type')]" />
      </Properties>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="property/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="concat(../../property[@name = 'type']/@value, '_', .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on the above input, the result is:

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1" />
    <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2" />
    <property name="a2_prop1" value="val1" />
    <property name="a2_prop2" value="val2" />
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```